# Unión de Dataframes con Spark mediante dos columnas

Tags: date, dataframe, join, pyspark, union

Estoy estudiando Big Data y se me presenta el siguiente problema en Spark databreaks.

Tengo tres dataframes, en formato csv, con tres columnas:

1. Precio Medio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Previsión demanda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Previsión eólica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las tres tablas tienen la misma cantidad de registros (10.000 filas) y mismas fechas y horas (24 horas por cada día), la única variación es la tercera columna de cada dataframe. Quiero unir en la primera tabla la tercera columna de las tablas 2 y 3 en función de la fecha y la hora.
El código que uso es el siguiente, pero me da error:

```
datos_md = precio_md.join(prev_demanda, on="fecha" and "hora", how="outer").join(prev_eolica, on="fecha" and "hora", how="outer").show()
```

También he intentado con el siguiente código:

```
datos_md = precio_md.join(prev_demanda.select("prev_demanda"), how="left").join(prev_eolica.select("prev_eolica"), how="left").show(40)
```

Y me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque con el primer código no me lo une en función de las filas, fecha y hora, y porque con el segundo código precio_md y prev_demanda, me coge el valor de la primera fila para todas las filas

No se cómo hacer para cada fecha y hora obtener una fila con los valores del precio, demanda y eolicidad.

¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme? Muchas gracias!!